# Add currency sign to prices

Tags: excel, vba

In Excel, I have a range `R1:W300` with variety of cells with prices, dates, percents, text etc.

I want only after all prices to put the currency sign.

I use the code below but it puts the currency sign to all data - not only the prices. How can I make it put the currency sign only on the prices?

```
Sub FormatCurrency()    
    Dim Sh As Worksheet   
    Set Sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)    

    Sh.Range("R1:W300").NumberFormat = "#,##0.00 $"
End Sub
```

Comment: Well, you need to make sure that you apply `.NumberFormat = "#,##0.00 $"` only to the cells with prices then. VBA cannot do any magic, it does not know which cells are the cells with prices. This is something you need to do. How do you distinguish which cell has a price and which is something else?

Comment: I distinguish which cell has a price by the format of the cell. For example cell with percent are formatted as percent: 20%. Cells with dates are formatted as dates: 18.11.2020. Cells with prices are formated as General: 20.25

Comment: Unless your spreadsheet is really disorganized, you probably have some columns that are currencies. Let's say columns R and W are currencies. You could say `Sh.Range("R1:R300").NumberFormat = "#,##0.00 $"` and then `Sh.Range("W1:W300").NumberFormat = "#,##0.00 $"`

Comment: @nikolaikolev In this case you would need to loop through all cells in `Sh.Range("R1:W300")` and check for each cell which `.NumberFormat` it has and let your code decide if it should be changed to `.NumberFormat = "#,##0.00 $"` or not.

Comment: No. R1 some times is a General number (20.45), sometimes is a percent (-20.45%), sometimes is a date (18.11.2020) - every time is different. I only need to add a currency sign when in a cell is a number formatted as "General" (Format Cells - tab Number - General)

Comment: @Pᴇʜ this is a great idea. Any ideas how the code would look like ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple loop and an `If` statement like below should do:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub FormatCurrency()    
    Dim Sh As Worksheet   
    Set Sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)    

    Dim Cell As Range
    For Each Cell In Sh.Range("R1:W300").Cells 'loop through all cells in that range
        If Cell.NumberFormat = "General" Then  'check if numberformat is General
            Cell.NumberFormat = "#,##0.00 $"   'if general change it to currency
        End If
    Next Cell
End Sub
```

Comment: That did the job just fine. Many thanx pal.